# How can I force a Julia package to redo precompilation?

Tags: caching, julia, precompile

I added a package to my Julia environment, and the package successfully precompiled. However, several log messages and errors were logged to the console. The errors seem to have been caught because they did not cause precompilation to fail.

How do I force a Julia package in my environment to redo precompilation?

Answer (score 1):

Julia packages are usually precompiled to `DEPOT_PATH[1]/compiled/v#.#/NameOfPackage` where `DEPOT_PATH[1]` is usually `~/.julia` in your home directory.

One way to force recompilation is to delete the cache files at the above location.

Another way is to invoke the following function with the name of the package as a `String`.

```
force_recompile(package_name::String) = Base.compilecache(Base.identify_package(package_name))
```

For packages imported via `Pkg.develop` or `] dev`, modify the package files will also force recompilation.